# Examine File Type (not Extension) before Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, upload

An extension of a file to be upload within a HTML form may be validated using JQuery's Valdation plugin:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-id">
   <input type="file" name="file-id" id="file-id" />
</form>
```

This may be validated by JQuery's Validation Plugin using the a rule

```
$("#form-id").validate({
    rules: {
        file-id: {
            extension: ["jpg","png","gif"]
        }
});
```

For our usage, simple extension validation is not sufficient as users tend to rename graphics their files before uploading without converting them. E.g. we retrieve a PDF graphics wich cannot be convert to e.g. png's by libgd.

Is there a way to examine the real content of a graphics file and prevent uploading not processable formats?

Comment: @stefan most fileformats have some kind of ID/Header in the start of the file so load first for example 128 Bytes (or more depend on the max needed offset from all supported fileformats) and check for each supproted filetype if ID found then all OK if not then throw it away as wrong file .... (google fileformat for each filetype you need there you will find all you need ...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible (or may be possible depending on the specific browser). The [HTML File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) allows you to get a file's MIME type. See the article [Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) for details, but the basic idea is as follows:

For a file input element:

```
<input type="file" id="file-input">
```

You can get the [FileList](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist) object, the File object(s) from that, each of which has a type property that resolves to a MIME type:

```
$("#file-input").on("change", function (evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    $.each(files, function (i, file) {
        if (file.type === "image/jpeg") {
            alert("It's a JPEG");
        }
        else if (file.type === "image/png") {
            alert("It's a PNG");
        }
        else {
            alert('The file MIME type is "' + file.type + '"');
        }
    });
});
```

If you need go beyond the MIME type, you can open and read the file's contents via the [FileReader API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader). Method readAsArrayBuffer will give you the file contents as an array of typed bytes.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the MIME type of the file.

If you are using the HTML file chooser you can get the type using:

```
document.getElementById('fileChooserID').files[0].type
```

Note that this will check the MIME type in the client side so it will not be enough. You can never trust the client side alone for validation.
In server side you should inspect the request `content-type` located on the request's `HEAD`.